# Unique id in c++

Tags: c++

So the question is to store id of 11 students and store their runs in a cricket match
the runs must be greater then 10 and the id number of students must be unique
i am only facing problem in creating a condition that when a user inputs same value the programm should tell that the value exists already and add a different value.l

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main() {
  int id[5];
  int run[5];
  int a, b, c, d, e, f;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j < 5; j++) {
      cout << "Enter id" << i << endl;
      cin >> id[i];
      if (id[i] == id[j]) {
        cout << "same id exists";
        cin >> id[i];
      }

      cout << "Enter runs of student \n";
      do {
        cout << "Runs must be greater or equal to 10 \n";
        cin >> run[i];
      } while (run[i] < 10);
    }
  }

  system("pause");
```

Comment: the loop is at the wrong place. You do not want to take user input 5 x 5 times. You want to take user intput 5 times and then compare the id with 5 others (actuall n-th input must be compared to only n-1 other ids)

Comment: Please use more punctuation to facilitate reading.

Comment: this is a good opportunity to learn how to use a debugger. It will show you what your code does and you will see how that differs from what it should do. Its only a small step then to fix it

Comment: You already know how to check an user input, you are doing it with the run-cin, using a do-while-loop. Why not try the same with the first input, but for IDs ? 
A heads up: you'll need to rework you for-loops and what to execute when. Maybe rename i to student_idx and j to run_idx to see why.

Answer (score 2):

You want to store the ids in a `std::set` (or `std::unordered_set`):

```
#include <unordered_set>

std::unordered_set<id_type> ids;
// . . .
if (auto [iter, is_inserted] = ids.insert(new_id); !is_inserted) {
    // take care of repeated id
}
```

And as [463035818-is-not-a-number](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4117728/463035818-is-not-a-number) points out if you need a student associated with each `id` use a `std::map` (or `std::unordered_map`):

```
#include <unordered_map>

std::unordered_map<id_type, stdent_type> students;
// . . . 
if (auto [iter, is_inserted] = students.emplace(new_id, new_student); !is_inserted) {
    // take care of repeated id 
}
```

Comment: or a `std::map< id , student >`

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager “Premature optimization is the root of all evil” Donald Knuth

Comment: its not premature. `do { std::cin >> new_id; } while( !ids.insert(new_id).second)` is more idomatic and simpler (and on top of that also more performant)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Just pointing out the general idea, not writing production code.

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager Ok, now the original idea is buried deeply within correct code.

Comment: I agree with @PaulEvans here. Before reading this thread of comments I was going to comment "why you overcomplicated the basic concept here?".
This is an answer to someone that is clearly at the very beginning of the learning process. He does not even know about vectors and you talk about inefficiency and generic types. This is the perfect way to make beginners run away from c++.

Comment: After the recent edits, my complaint about double-hashing is not relevant any more. I deleted the comment.

Comment: @Federico I think that explaining why "`if not contains then insert` pattern is a bad practice because of double hashing" is very useful also for juniors. If someone runs away from C++ after this, then I am pretty sure they will run into the very same problem in any other language. After spending many years with StackOverflow I can say for sure this is not the right place where absolute beginners are supposed to learn their very first steps. Programming is a complex craft and let's not pretend it is not. `if not contains then insert` pattern must not pass any code review. Period.